# Measuring flood mitigation effectiveness in river at different time using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, flood

I am trying to measure the effectiveness of flood mitigation in a river using ArcGIS 10.2. Data available to me are the left and right bank polyline of 4 years , settlement data and point data where the mitigation is applied. We have applied river mitigation measures at the end of first year so that its effect is seen at the end of 2nd, 3rd and 4th year.(Like the shift of river, change in the area of river and effect on the settlements near the banks of river).

Is there any way I can measure the effectiveness of the mitigation applied using ArcGIS Desktop tools?

Comment: If you wish to ask a similar question about QGIS (which was tagged but not mentioned in your question) please do that in a separate question.

Comment: @PolyGeo  I don't know it will be marked as duplicate?

Comment: If it is about QGIS and if this one is about ArcGIS Desktop then they should not be marked as duplicates.  If they are, flag for a moderator to ask for it to be re-opened, or just ping me.  Make sure that you describe precisely what you have tried using the software of focus in each question.

Comment: Could you post pictures of the data? Are the poly lines representing just the edges of the river under normal flow or during flood events? If flood events were they the same return period / peak events? What is your definition of effectiveness? Reduction in properties affected? Keeping the flood levels in a range?